# Archer GRC: Importing multiple sources of data into an application

Tags: datafeed, rsa-archer-grc, archer

I'd like to have data from different sources be imported into an application with data feed but also differentiate between the two sources. The sources come from an MS SQL database and a CSV file from a shared drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **value lists** through MS SQL and CSV file imports. Based on the import type you can assign values to the fields.

Comment: @igrite and (Radha) - I am trying to tag all the Archer questions with a new Archer tag I am trying to create -- please reply and let's see if we can get together to get them all tagged... thx